# Call a <macrodef> for each <pathelement> in a <path> in Ant

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I have a `path` as follows:

```
<path refid="myjarlocation"/>
```

Now I want to iterate over this path and for each value present in the path I want to call a macrodef with that value as one of the property to be used inside the marcodef.

In case of target we can easily do it as follows:

```
<foreach target="mytarget" param="jarloc">
    <path refid="myjarlocation"/>
</foreach>
```

I cannot use for each because I need to pass multiple parameters , so I am using macrodef. So, therefore the question how to iterate over a path and call a macrodef instead of  a target.

Comment: What do you mean by `iterate over this path`?

Comment: This is how my path would look like

<path id="myjarlocation">
<pathelement location="1.jar" />
<pathelement location="2.jar" />
</path>

By iterating ,I need to retrieve each location i.e. "1.jar" , "2.jar" and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made something similar work by using ant-contrib's `for` task to iterate a path and passing the path element along to a macrodef.

First get ant-contrib in your project - see http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/

Next, define your macrodef in your ant build however you want including some attribute that will take your path element. eg:

```
<macrodef name="awesome-macro">
    <attribute name="path-to-deal-with"/>
    <attribute name="unrelated-attribute"/>
    <sequential>
        ...
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Then, use the `for` task to iterate the path into pathelements and invoke the macro:

```
<for param="path.element">
    <fileset dir="${jars.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <sequential>
        <awesome-macro path-to-deal-with="@{path.element}" unrelated-attribute="whatever"/>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

Note the use of `@{path.element}` as opposed to `${path.element}` inside the for loop to refer to the looping parameter!